# Derivation of natural log inequality

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds

While looking at a proof of this inequality

$(1+\frac{1}{x})^x < e < (1+\frac{1}{x})^{(x+1)}$

The authors take the natural log of on both sides and get

$xln(1+\frac{1}{x}) < 1 < (x+1)ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$

But then they write this last inequality as follows (which I don't understand)

$\frac{1}{1+x} <ln(1+\frac{1}{x}) < 1/x $

How can you re-write the second inequality as the third inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the known equation
$$
x \ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right) < 1 < (x+1) \ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)
$$
This is, in fact, two different results:
$$
x \ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right) < 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 1 < (x+1) \ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)
$$
When you divide both sides of the **first** equation by $x > 0$ and both sides of the **second** equation by $(x+1)$, you get
$$
\ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right) < \frac{1}{x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{1}{x+1} <\ln\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)
$$
Can you see it now?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks very much!